# Custom CSS for jquery-mobile. Center collapsible header

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I want to center the header text of a collapsible in jquery-mobile application.

My Code is:

```
<div data-role="content">
         <ul data-role="listview" id="sortingOptionsList">

         <li><div data-role="collapsible">
            <h3 class="custom-centercollheader">Editar</h3> <-- IMPORTANT


            <p>I'm the collapsible content. By default I'm closed, but you can click the header to open me.</p>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li><input type="button" value="Crear Hijo"></li>
         <li><input type="button" value="Eliminar"></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
```

I have a reference to a custom.css file I've created, where i have:

```
.custom-centercollheader {
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

However, when I open the page, the css give preference to the css of jquery-mobile:

```
.ui-collapsible-heading .ui-btn {
text-align: left;
```

How can I give preference to my custom css??

Comment: depending on how the CSS is loaded yours may be overwritten. Can you set up a fiddle showcasing the issue? Also, have you tried giving that element an `id` and using that instead (it may work via specificity).

Comment: Link or jsfiddle please

Answer (score 2):

The collapsible header text is actually in an anchor tag within the header tag. So your css should be:

```
.custom-centercollheader a {
    text-align: center !important;
    padding-right: 2.5em !important;
}
```

I added the right padding because the expand icon button on the left moves the anchor off center.  By providing the same padding on the right, the text will be centered and aligned with the buttons below it.

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/8Mzye/)**